# Duplicate Table Paragraphs in Docx created with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI in order to create a docx containing a table.

In order to format the table, I'm adding paragraphs to the cell, using this method:

```
private XWPFParagraph getTableParagraph(XWPFDocument document, XWPFParagraph paragraph, String text, boolean bold, boolean wrap, boolean allineaDx){
    if (paragraph == null) paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun p2run = paragraph.createRun();

    p2run.setText(text);

    p2run.setFontSize(5);
    p2run.setBold(bold);

    if (wrap) paragraph.setWordWrap(wrap);
    if (allineaDx) paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

    return paragraph;
}
```

and I call the method with:

```
        XWPFTableRow tableOneRowOne = tableOne.getRow(0);
        tableOneRowOne.getCell(0).setParagraph(getTableParagraph(document, tableOneRowOne.getCell(0).getParagraphArray(0), "some text", true, true, false));
```

the table comes out as desired, but all the paragraphs created and inserted in the cells are also visible at the end of the table. Why? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

problem solved

the duplication was caused by document.createParagraph().

i changed the method into this:

```
private XWPFParagraph getTableParagraph(XWPFTableCell cell, String text, boolean bold, boolean wrap, boolean allineaDx) throws Exception{

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
    cell.removeParagraph(0);

    XWPFRun p2run = paragraph.createRun();

    p2run.setText(text);

    p2run.setFontSize(5);
    p2run.setBold(bold);

    if (wrap) paragraph.setWordWrap(wrap);
    if (allineaDx) paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

    return paragraph;
}
```

and now everything works just fine. Please note the cell.removeParagraph(0)

Cells come with a null paragraph on their own, and adding a new paragraph ends up in having duplicated paragraph inside the cell. Removing the original paragraph works fine.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked for me as well. Strange that the cell comes with it's own paragraph already