# Apache POI word, how to remove the white space (new line) from beginning of table cell?

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I am only able to style the contents of a table cell using paragraph element to change the color of the text for example. 
When i create a paragraph inside the table it creates a new line. For my project i need these cell to be as small as possible for that i am using

```
   tr.setHeight(300);
   tr.getCtRow().getTrPr().getTrHeightArray(0).setHRule(STHeightRule.EXACT);
```

that works when there is no blank lines.

the code below is the problem

```
    XWPFTable tb = document.createTable(2,2);
    XWPFParagraph p1 =  tb.getRow(0).getCell(0).addParagraph();
    XWPFRun p1run = p1.createRun();
    p1run.setText("why is there a space");
    XWPFParagraph p2 =  tb.getRow(1).getCell(1).addParagraph();
    XWPFRun p2run = p2.createRun();
    p2run.setText("still there ");
```

This create this output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSONW.png

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution here..
[Duplicate Table Paragraphs in Docx created with Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24660448/duplicate-table-paragraphs-in-docx-created-with-apache-poi)

It seems you add a paragraph then remove the original with this code:

```
XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
cell.removeParagraph(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a paragraph clearing text in cell worked for me

```
cell.clearText();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works >>

Use cell.getParagraphs().get(0) instead of cell.**addParagraph**().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).